# How to insert my HTML/template inside each <body> tag?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, markaby

I would like to insert a piece of arbitrary HTML code (or preferably another Markaby template) inside the `<body>` tag in each of my webapp pages.

I'm using Markaby which means that a template is (more or less) a Ruby class and `body` is its method. So it must be possible to write some Ruby code to intercept the `body` method call and to insert my HTML.

How do I do that with Sinatra?

Answer (score 0):

What's preventing you from using  `<%= yield %>` in your layout? For example, the code below will render your current view inside the layout's `<body>` tags by using `<%= yield %>`

In this case the template is `layout.erb` and the page is `hello.erb`. `hello.erb` is rendered within `layout.erb` in place of the `<%= yield %>`statement. Is this what you meant?

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/hello/:name' do
  @name = params[:name]
  erb :hello
end

__END__
@@ layout
<html>
  <body>
   <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>

@@ hello
<h3>Hello <%= @name %>!</h3>
```

Code from [About.com - Sinatra](http://ruby.about.com/od/sinatra/a/sinatra2.htm)

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but what I really need is something like I posted in another answer

Answer (score 0):

That can be done by redefining the `body` method in Markaby `Builder` class. This piece of code will do it:

```
class Markaby::Builder
  alias body_orig body
  def body(*args, &block)
    str = capture(&block)
    block = proc { text('ON EVERY PAGE' + str) }
    body_orig(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

And this one will include another Markaby template as the first thing inside the `body` tag:

```
class Markaby::Builder
  alias body_orig body
  def body(*args, &block)
    str = capture(&block)
    str2 = render :mab, :include_template_name, *args
    block = proc { text(str2 + str) }
    body_orig(*args, &block)
  end
end
```